# JavaScript / css not working in Sharepoint WebPart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload my page into sharePoint but I'm getting this error

"warning:html source you entered might have been modified"

however the javascript is not working nor css.

I tried to get around this problem by putting the code into a text file in the Site Assets document library.

http://bytelab.blogspot.com/2011/01/warning-html-source-you-entered-might.html

But with no luck,

P.S: I'm using sepprate files for html, JS, CSS

Comment: Can you provide some code samples, 
Basicly Sharepoint strips out "harmfull" tags.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the approach mentioned in the blog post [linked](http://bytelab.blogspot.com/2011/01/warning-html-source-you-entered-might.html) you referenced in your question. Placing the code in an external file makes managing and debugging much easier. Try these steps to get your code working:

1. Create a file in Notepad (or a similar text editor) with the following content: `alert("Hello World!");`
2. Save the file as `test.js`
3. Upload the file to a document library in SharePoint
4. Once the file is uploaded, copy the full URL to the file. In most browsers, you can copy the full URL by right clicking on the link and selecting "Copy Link To Clipboard". The link should look like http://yoursharepointsite.com/SiteAssets/test.js.
5. Browse to a Web Part Page in SharePoint. This is any page you can insert a Web Part.
6. As described in the blog post you linked to, add a Content Editor Web Part and set the Content Link to the full URL of your test.js file (from step 4).
7. Save the changes to the web part and the page. When the page is reloaded, you should receive and alert with the text "Hello World".

If you don't receive an alert, press F12 to open the Developer Tools for your browser. Locate the JavaScript console in the Developer Tools and refresh the page. You should see an error with the cause of the problem.

If you receive the alert then you can replace the URL in the Content Link with the full URL to your JavaScript file (or HTML file). If it's not working as expected, use the Developer Tools to track down the source of the problem. The following website has instructions on opening the Developer Tools on most major browsers:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors